# Comparing two nested dictionaries and storing the differences of their values into a new dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have one dictionary (long_dict) filled with 3 categories of data of different persons. I am trying to compare the values of a specific category (category_2) and store their differences separately into a new dictionary.

```
long_dict = {

'PERSON1':{
'category_1' :{
},
'category_2': {
'a': 20,
'b': 40,
'c': 60,
'd': 45
},
'category_3': {
}
},

'PERSON2': {
'category_1' :{
},
'category_2': {
'a': 30,
'b': 10,
'c': 40,
'd': 55
},
'category_3': {
}
},

'PERSON3': {
'category_1' :{
},
'category_2': {
'a': 60,
'b': 10,
'c': 35,
'd': 25
},
'category_3: {
}
},
'PERSON4': {
'category_1' :{
},
'category_2': {
'a': 30,
'b': 15,
'c': 65,
'd': 55
},
'category_3': {
}
}
}
```

I am looking to build a dict which stores the differences of values; something like this.

```
result = {

'PERSON1':{
'PERSON2' :{
'diff_a': ...,
'diff_b': ...,
'diff_c': ...,
'diff_d': ...
},
'PERSON3': {
'diff_a': ...,
'diff_b': ...,
'diff_c': ...,
'diff_d': ...
},
'PERSON4': {
'diff_a': ...,
'diff_b': ...,
'diff_c': ...,
'diff_d': ...
}
},
'PERSON2':{
'PERSON1' :{
'diff_a': ...,
'diff_b': ...,
'diff_c': ...,
'diff_d': ...
},
'PERSON3': {
'diff_a': ...,
'diff_b': ...,
'diff_c': ...,
'diff_d': ...
},
'PERSON4': {
'diff_a': ...,
'diff_b': ...,
'diff_c': ...,
'diff_d': ...
 }
 },
'PERSON3':{
'PERSON1' :{
'diff_a': ...,
'diff_b': ...,
'diff_c': ...,
'diff_d': ...
},
'PERSON2': {
'diff_a': ...,
'diff_b': ...,
'diff_c': ...,
'diff_d': ...
},
'PERSON4': {
'diff_a': ...,
'diff_b': ...,
'diff_c': ...,
'diff_d': ...
}
},

'PERSON4':{
'PERSON1' :{
'diff_a': ...,
'diff_b': ...,
'diff_c': ...,
'diff_d': ...
},
'PERSON2': {
'diff_a': ...,
'diff_b': ...,
'diff_c': ...,
'diff_d': ...
},
'PERSON3': {
'diff_a': ...,
'diff_b': ...,
'diff_c': ...,
'diff_d': ...
}
}
}
```

So far, I've tried this:

```
abc = dict()
xyz = dict()
fin = dict()
i = 0
for k, v in long_dict.items():
for a, b in long_dict.items():
    if k != a:
        for k2, v2 in v.items():
            for a2, b2 in b.items():
                if k2 == a2 == "category_2":
                    for k3, v3 in v2.items():
                        for a3, b3 in b2.items():
                            if k3 == a3:
                                abc[k3] = abs(v3-b3)
        xyz[a] = abc
        i+=1                        
        if i > 3:
            fin[k] = xyz
            i=0
```

And, this is what I get on print(fin):

```
{'PERSON2': {'PERSON2': {'a': 30, 'b': 5, 'c': 30, 'd': 30}, 'PERSON3': {'a': 30, 'b': 5, 'c': 30, 'd': 30}, 'PERSON4': {'a': 30, 'b': 5, 'c': 30, 'd': 30}, 'PERSON1': {'a': 30, 'b': 5, 'c': 30, 'd': 30}}, 'PERSON3': {'PERSON2': {'a': 30, 'b': 5, 'c': 30, 'd': 30}, 'PERSON3': {'a': 30, 'b': 5, 'c': 30, 'd': 30}, 'PERSON4': {'a': 30, 'b': 5, 'c': 30, 'd': 30}, 'PERSON1': {'a': 30, 'b': 5, 'c': 30, 'd': 30}}, 'PERSON4': {'PERSON2': {'a': 30, 'b': 5, 'c': 30, 'd': 30}, 'PERSON3': {'a': 30, 'b': 5, 'c': 30, 'd': 30}, 'PERSON4': {'a': 30, 'b': 5, 'c': 30, 'd': 30}, 'PERSON1': {'a': 30, 'b': 5, 'c': 30, 'd': 30}}}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the expected output? For instance, should the "difference" between values change depending on the direction of the comparison since you are storing each comparison twice? For example, `{'PERSON1': {'PERSON2': {'a': -10}}, 'PERSON2': {'PERSON1': {'a': 10}}`. As an aside, there may be a much better, more efficient way to get and store the data you need but that would require a brief explanation of what you are trying to do with this data.

Comment: @benvc, 
1) Values are non-directional; only absolute values
2) This is basically a comparison between people on a certain category (say, Strengths). In this category, there are several datapoints (like, self-efficacy, boldness, etc). So, essentially, we are comparing these datapoints. 

The source data is a json file (long_dict), which contains the nested dicts with peoples names and "Strengths" and other categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more efficient way of comparing and storing the values would be to only compare and store each unique comparison once (rather than comparing and storing the same comparison for each dict key involved in the comparison). You could use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to keep it fairly simple and access each comparison by a tuple key (the approach below assumes that the each of the compared category dicts contains the same keys - if not, then you would have to add some additional checking).

```
from itertools import combinations

d = {'PERSON1':{'category_1' :{}, 'category_2': {'a': 20, 'b': 40, 'c': 60, 'd': 45}, 'category_3': {}}, 'PERSON2': {'category_1' :{}, 'category_2': {'a': 30, 'b': 10, 'c': 40, 'd': 55}, 'category_3': {}}, 'PERSON3': {'category_1' :{}, 'category_2': {'a': 60, 'b': 10, 'c': 35, 'd': 25}, 'category_3': {}}, 'PERSON4': {'category_1' :{}, 'category_2': {'a': 30, 'b': 15, 'c': 65, 'd': 55}, 'category_3': {}}}

compare = {}
for a, b in combinations(sorted(d.keys()), 2):
    acat = d[a]['category_2']
    bcat = d[b]['category_2']
    compare[(a, b)] = {k: abs(acat[k] - bcat[k]) for k in acat}

print(compare)
# {('PERSON1', 'PERSON2'): {'a': 10, 'b': 30, 'c': 20, 'd': 10}, ('PERSON1', 'PERSON3'): {'a': 40, 'b': 30, 'c': 25, 'd': 20}, ('PERSON1', 'PERSON4'): {'a': 10, 'b': 25, 'c': 5, 'd': 10}, ('PERSON2', 'PERSON3'): {'a': 30, 'b': 0, 'c': 5, 'd': 30}, ('PERSON2', 'PERSON4'): {'a': 0, 'b': 5, 'c': 25, 'd': 0}, ('PERSON3', 'PERSON4'): {'a': 30, 'b': 5, 'c': 30, 'd': 30}}
```

Comment: you made my day! Thank you for the solution. Beautiful code. Smooth. :)